# How to get the controller's state name?

Tags: angular-ui-router

I want to know the state's name for which a controller was configured, not the current state.

Notice on the following jsfiddle that I'm initiating the route using `location.hash` and passing the desired state name using the resolve mechanism which I want to avoid:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/xzkh3kd5/

```
location.hash = '/a/b/c';

var template = '<div><h2>{{ current }} vs {{ wanted }}</h2><ui-view></ui-view></div>';

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/a');

    $stateProvider
        .state('a', {
            url       : '/a',
            template  : template,
            controller: 'default',
            resolve   : {
                wanted: function () {

                    return 'a';
                }
            }
        })
        .state('a.b', {
            url       : '/b',
            template  : template,
            controller: 'default',
            resolve   : {
                wanted: function () {

                    return 'a.b';
                }
            }
        })
        .state('a.b.c', {
            url       : '/c',
            template  : template,
            controller: 'default',
            resolve   : {
                wanted: function () {

                    return 'a.b.c';
                }
            }
        })
    ;
});

app.controller('default', function ($scope, $state, wanted) {

    $scope.current = $state.current.name;
    $scope.wanted  = wanted;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have a nice workaround for this, and is adding the wanted state name while configuring the states using some inheritance:

**A) Iterating an array of states configs**

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/xzkh3kd5/1/

```
states.forEach(function (state) {

    var controller = state.config.controller;

    state.config.controller = function ($scope, $controller) {

        $scope.wanted = state.name;

        angular.extend(this, $controller(controller, {
            $scope: $scope
        }));
    };

    $stateProvider.state(state.name, state.config);
});
```

**B) Overriding the state method**

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/xzkh3kd5/2/

```
var state = $stateProvider.state;

$stateProvider.state = function (name, config) {

    var controller = config.controller;

    config.controller = function ($scope, $controller) {

        $scope.wanted = name;

        angular.extend(this, $controller(controller, {
            $scope: $scope
        }));
    };

    return state.apply($stateProvider, arguments);
};
```

Looking towards a better solution.